# Logging slurm resource usage to file

Tags: slurm

Is there a way to log resource usage (as would be shown by `seff`) to a file upon job completion? Often I have jobs which have finished and their resource information have been cycled out of SLURM, leaving me no way to check them. I would like to either be able to have it be recorded in the log file where stdout and stderr go, or in a separate file upon job completion.

Answer (score 0):

The `seff` command is just a wrapper around the `sacct` command. If jobs are pruned from the database in a regular manner, you can run `seff` or `sacct` with the proper arguments at the end of your submission script. That way, it will execute right at the end of the job and write the results in the output file.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how that might look?

Comment: add `seff` as the last line in your submission script